# XSS Validation, Prevention or Cure?

Tags: security, antixsslibrary

I am having hands on trying to make a hack-proof website and learning about XSS. So the process is

A: Get User Input -> B: Store It -> C: Show It Again To client

I am using Microsoft AntiXSS library to avoid XSS attacks, but, the confusion is, should I perform required steps to avoid XSS attacks at step 'B' or at Step 'C'.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform the sanitisation at the point where you are presenting the content, because this is the only point where it matters.

In a more complicated scenario, your data-flow may look like this:

```
                          /---> C (presentation)
A (get input) -> B (store) 
                          \---> D (process)
```

If you've already sanitised the data at point B, then the processing at point D won't be able to operate on the original data.

Comment: Yes this is a case, but for another case, if I want to create a feedback section where user is just supposed to enter some plain text then should I perform it on step B, as it will save a lot of processing overhead every time admin moderates the feedback. So I think it depends upon the scenario to perform sanitation at step B or at step C.

Comment: @Nishant: that would be an optimisation. Optimisation often involves sacrificing the clean/natural architecture.

Comment: I'm the AntiXSS owner. I agree with Oli's advice - encode at the point of output. What happens if your output changes, say from HTML to XML - the rules are slightly different and if you've pre-encoded in one then you rule out working in another.

Comment: Just remember that Validation and Encoding are not the same thing

Comment: Here's the OWASP recommendation to do it on C: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.236_-_Use_an_HTML_Policy_engine_to_validate_or_clean_user-driven_HTML_in_an_outbound_way